# ethereum window event listener always false

Tags: javascript, ethereum

I am using the follwing code but the window.ethereum is always false so the promise is always resolved with undefined. I am using metamask

```
window.addEventListener("load", async () => {
            if(window.ethereum) {
                await window.ethereum.enable();
                const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
                const signer = provider.getSigner();
                
                const paymentProcessor = new Contract(
                    PaymentProcessor.networks[window.ethereum.networkVersion].address,
                    PaymentProcessor.abi,
                    signer
                );
                
                const dai = new Contract(
                    Dai.networks[window.ethereum.networkVersion].address,
                    Dai.abi,
                    signer
                );

                resolve({provider, paymentProcessor, dai});
            }

            resolve({provider: undefined, paymentProcessor: undefined, dai: undefined});
        });
    });
```

what is wrong

Comment: It may be a stupid question but, did you install metamask or any other ethereum provider?

Comment: yeah i am using metamask. sorry i will update the question